# How to convert a wxPython app to run as a headless unix job?

Tags: python, linux, wxwidgets

I am currently running 2.8.9.1 of wx in a linux box.

The App I am working on was originally written to run on MS Windows. We are planning to port part of the core logic to linux and run it as a process.

The problem is that the linux box is headless. We will not have a X-windows environment. But the existing codebase was written in such a way that it is tightly coupled with the wx layer.

For example, I have a couple of classes which are subclass of wx.EvtHandler

I probably can rewrite them one by one, but it is really not ideal.

In the new wx Pheonix, there is an  [AppConsole class](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/AppConsole.html#appconsole) which seems to be able to start an event loop without X-Windows. However it is not available in my local version of wx.

The Goal is ultimately to **run the code in a cron job**

I am basically looking for some advices/pointers as to how to tackle this issue. It would be nice to avoid as much rewrite as possible.

Comment: Have you tried [vncserver](http://www.tightvnc.com/)?

Comment: @TurboJ Thanks for the suggestion. I have clarifed my objective in my question. I cannot have a dependency on external server/workstation for the sake of a X-Window session

Comment: With vncserver you *don't* have an external dependency. The vncserver runs as a local X server.

Comment: @TurboJ I see. Sorry, the environment is a bit 'enterpricy', so i think it is easier to rewrite then requesting installation of a vncserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the rewriting is not too bad.

There are only three dependencies on wx objects in my code

1) subclassing wx.EvtHandler

2) wx.CallLater

3) wx.CallAfter

So the first case requires a reimplmentation

The other can be replaced by threading.Timer  easily.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to to use your local display. [`Ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) into your server with option `-X` to redirect the display to your workstation

```
ssh -X server
```

And on your server start the application, which will use your workstation's display automatically.

For Windows, there exists [Xming](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xming) or [Cygwin](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) for example.

As an alternative, you can use [`Xvfb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which provides a headless X server. You can then start your application by using `xvfb-run` as

```
xvfb-run my_wx_application
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not fit my use case. Eventually I want to run the core code as a cron job. I do not want to have an external workstation

Comment: @AnthonyKong If you want to run truly headless, you might consider xvfb, which is still a X server. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Xvfb sounds interesting. However the linux box lives in an 'enterprise' environment, so it is hard to request additional/external software. I am looking for some way to start a wx event loop without a full X-windows. i.e. preferably a solution at the source code level. Afterall it makes sense to decouple business logic from the presentation layer.